# Rails i18n: separate language key at the end of the tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

So I use Ruby on Rails 3.2 with the awesome i18n module.

I'm still not 100% sure of how file and key structuring works, but I got it working in my case:

`my_file.yml` (apparently filename doesn't matter):

```
en:
  first:
    second:
      key: 'Hello Stackoverflow'
fr:
  first:
    second:
      key: 'Bonjour Stackoverflow'
```

And in my views:

```
= t('first.second.key') # will return the sting
```

But I would much rather have the following paths:

```
first:
  second:
    key: 
      en: 'Hello Stackoverflow'
      fr: 'Bonjour Stackoverflow'
```

**Can I achieve this?**

I see the following advantages doing that:

- **Easier to maintain**: if a key is changed it needs to be changed only once
- **Easier to translate**: different language versions are alonside. It is obvious if a translation is missing
- **Better file management**: organize files by content and not languages
- **Better to handle default value**: imagine a key is not to be translated in any language. You could write

`translations.yml`:

```
not_translatable_key: 'Stackoverflow'
translatable_key:
  en: 'is awesome'
  fr: 'est génial'
```

If it is not possible, I may customize i18n my own way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a warning : how do you get custom I18n values (like `count`) ?

If you really want to do this, maybe you can overwrite the `load_yml` function of `/i18n/backend/base.rb`...

```
def load_yml(filename)
  begin
    result = YAML.load_file(filename)
    reverse_keys(result)
  rescue TypeError, ScriptError, StandardError => e
    raise InvalidLocaleData.new(filename, e.inspect)
  end
end
```

Then, a function `reverse_keys` returns to a standard I18n file format...

```
h = { :translatable_key => { :en => 'is awesome', :fr => 'est trop cool' } }

reverse_keys(h)
=> { :en => { :translatable_key => 'is awesome' },
     :fr => { :translatable_key => 'est trop cool' } }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that around. Could you detail the `custom I18n values` warning a little more? I may indeed have missed something...